# Permission issue in linux file system

Tags: linux, informatica

Actually, I have a directory which has full permission (`drwxrwxrwx`) but i have a process which creates a file in this directory by using another user and problem is that files which is created by process has not enough permission (`-r-xr--r--`) that's why i am facing problem. So, is there any way to give the permissions by which created file also have complete permissions?

One more thing we would like to highlight that the process which creates this file is **Informatica workflow**.

Please assist.

Comment: What is the file mode mask setting of this 'another user'? Run `umask` under this user will give the current setting.

Comment: it is 0000 for that particular user

Comment: What is the `mode` setting of `open()` call used to create this file? And the umask value before this `open()` call (call `getumask()`)? If you can, run your program in a debugger or add print statements to output their values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a command task after the session with the command `chmod 777 <filename>`

Comment: no we can't change the permission of file bcoz it is temp file which is generated by one session and at same time another session use it

Comment: You can still use the command task in between the two sessions if the sessions are connected serially. Where are you facing the permission issues anyway? In the second session or in some other external script?

Comment: You can have command task following the session in the same workflow. Or even use post session command task. This should be executed as part of the session run.

Answer (score 0):

Try setGID bit.Change the permission to 2770 on the directory.  This  will give specials permissions  and your file has necessary permissions. **chmod 2770**